# sql subquery that collects from 3 rows

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a huge database with over 4 million rows that look like that:

```
Customer ID Shop 
1           Asda 
1           Sainsbury
1           Tesco 
2           TEsco 
2           Tesco
```

I need to count customers that within last 4 weeks had shopped in all 3 shops Tesco Sainsbury and Asda. Can you please advice if its possible to do it with subqueries?

Comment: Does your table have a date column in it?  Have to tried to write the query to return the result?  Please post your table structure as well as any attempts that you made to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  You can solve it with aggregation:

```
select customer_id
from Yourtable t
where <shopping date within last four weeks>
group by customer_id
having sum(case when shop = 'Asda' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when shop = 'Sainsbury' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when shop = 'Tesco' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

This structure is quite flexible.  So if you wanted Asda and Tesco but not Sainsbury, then you would do:

```
select customer_id
from Yourtable t
where <shopping date within last four weeks>
group by customer_id
having sum(case when shop = 'Asda' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when shop = 'Sainsbury' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when shop = 'Tesco' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

EDIT:

If you want a count, then use this as a subquery and count the results:

```
select count(*)
from (select customer_id
      from Yourtable t
      where <shopping date within last four weeks>
      group by customer_id
      having sum(case when shop = 'Asda' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when shop = 'Sainsbury' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when shop = 'Tesco' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
     ) t
```

Comment: that is great thank you so much. I am still new to the sql so sorry if this question sounds stupid but can i say select count(customer_id) at the beginning of the query if want just the volume not all of the customer_ids? thanks

Comment: select count(*)
from (select a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
      from dm3_owner.EARN_FACT a left join pad_owner.ssl_stores c on a.location_code=c.locn_code
      where a.tran_date_id between '20130626' and '20130701'
      group by a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
      having sum(case when c.STORE_FORMAT = 'CONVENIENCE STORES' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when c.STORE_FORMAT = 'PETROL STATIONS' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when c.STORE_FORMAT = 'SUPERSTORES' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
     )dm3_owner.EARN_FACT a   but it doesnt work